# Web scraping with requests - selecting filter in website

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm using the following code to get the top 20 pdf's from the AMF website(https://bdif.amf-france.org). I'm trying to be more specific and download only the "Déclaration des dirigeants"  but I don't know how to do this. How can I integrate this filter in the url? Something like https://bdif.amf-france.org/back/api/v1/informations?from=0&size=2?typesInformation=DD . Can anyone help?

```
import requests
from shutil import copyfileobj

endpoint = "https://bdif.amf-france.org/back/api/v1/informations?from=0&size=20"
base_api_url = "https://bdif.amf-france.org/back/api/v1/documents"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
    file_sources = [
        [
            f"{base_api_url}/{item['_source']['documents'][0]['path']}",  # Document
            item["_source"]["documents"][0]["nomFichier"]  # File name
        ]
        for item in response["hits"]["hits"]
]

for file in file_sources:
    url, name = file
    with s.get(url, stream=True) as pdf, open(name, "wb") as output:
        copyfileobj(pdf.raw, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `typesInformation` parameter to `DD` in your url like this:

```
endpoint = 'https://bdif.amf-france.org/back/api/v1/informations?from=0&size=20&typesInformation=DD'
```